# OpenCV - Does there exist a function to do BOW (Bag-of-Words) in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, vectorization, feature-extraction

I have to use OpenCV 2.4.6 to do BOW(Bag of Words), all my code is c++. Now I want to do it in python.

I have searched the OpenCV-python reference (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/). But I didn't get the answer. Then from http://answers.opencv.org/question/10870/python-wrapper-for-bow/, I know maybe there is not OpenCV-python for bow. Can anyone find it?

Since I have trained the vocabulary using C++, now when I get a photo I want to get the BOW vector compare with the vocabulary. C++ uses `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor()` function do it. Is there exist the python code like `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor()`?

Comment: No python bindings for BoW yet. Need to wait.

Comment: Thanks, Abid, I have compiled c++ function as a module for python, and it has done well now.

Comment: If you have added python bindings for bow, you can contribute it to opencv.

Comment: I have list some of code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have write a sample code like this, 
(1)first of all, we use python c++ api to train bow vocabulary and save it to file.
(2) write c++ code to get image's bow vectorization representation
the code is :

```
vector<double> features;//store the feature
bool readVocabulary(const string& filename, Mat& vocabulary) {
    FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::READ);
    if (fs.isOpened()) {
        fs["vocabulary"] >> vocabulary;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//imgpath is the image filepath, vocpath is the voc path
void getImgBow(char* imgpath, char* vocpath) {
    cv::initModule_nonfree();
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descExtractor =
            DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> descMatcher =
            DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
    Ptr<BOWImgDescriptorExtractor> bowExtractor;
    if (featureDetector.empty() || descExtractor.empty() || descMatcher.empty()) {
        cout << "featureDetector or descExtractor was not created" << endl;
    }
    bowExtractor = new BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(descExtractor, descMatcher);
    Mat vocabulary;
    readVocabulary(vocpath, vocabulary);
    bowExtractor->setVocabulary(vocabulary);
    Mat img = imread(imgpath);
    if (img.rows < img.cols)
        cv::resize(img, img, Size(320, 240));
    else
        cv::resize(img, img, Size(240, 320));
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    Mat descriptors;
    featureDetector->detect(img, keypoints);
    bowExtractor->compute(img, keypoints, descriptors);
    for (int j = 0; j < descriptors.cols; j++) {
        float value = descriptors.at<float> (0, j);
        features.push_back(value);
    }
}
```

(3), we encode the c++ code as python module:

```
PyObject* wrap_contentfilter(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
//parse the python parameters.
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "sssOO", &imgpath, &vocpath, &modelpath,
            &candidate_list, &can_pro_lsit))
//you may use PyInt_AsSsize_t and so on to do type change.
//invoke getImgBow function.
//construct PyObject and return to python, use PyList_SetItem function,PyObject*
}

static PyMethodDef predictMethods[] = { { "content_filter", wrap_contentfilter,
        METH_VARARGS, "get image's bow, predict" }, { NULL, NULL } };
extern "C" 
void initcontentfilter() {
    PyObject* m;
    m = Py_InitModule("contentfilter", predictMethods);
}
```

(4)we write a python example to invoke the c++ function.

```
import contentfilter
 contentfilter.content_filter(parameters)
```

(5) compile c++ function:

```
g++ -fPIC  content_filter.cpp -o contentfilter.so  -shared -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/config -L/usr/local/lib  -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

(6) python example.py